# Proving $a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $p\in\mathbb{P}$

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, solution-verification

I'm tasked with proving $a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $p\in\mathbb{P}$ using a "variation" of the contrapositive strategy. Particularly, I am to assume $a$ and $p$ are positive integers, that $a^p \not\equiv a \pmod{p}$, and show that this sufficient for $p \not\in\mathbb{P}$.

---

Here's where I've gotten so far (admittedly, not far):

Suppose $a$ and $p$ are positive integers. Suppose also that $a^p \not\equiv a \pmod{p}$. We may then conclude that $a^p \neq a + pk$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $\gcd(a^p-a, p)=1$. By *Bezout's Lemma*, there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $1 = (a^{p-1})x + (p)y$. Re-arranging this expression, $p = \frac{1 - (a^{p-1})x}{y}$.

---

It would be nice if I could then conclude that $y\mid p$. I don't see an obvious path toward this, however.

How might I proceed (I ask that a full solution *not* be given)?

**EDIT:**

Another thought... if $y$ is to divide $p$, then $y$ must divide $1-a^{p-1}x$. Equivalently, $yj = 1 - a^{p-1}x$, or $yj + a^{p-1}x = 1$. Well, we have such a $j$ already... namely, $p$.

Not sure if I'm actually going anywhere with this, though.

---

**EDIT:**

Here's where I am now:

Suppose that $a$ and $p$ are positive integers, and also that $a^p \not\equiv a\pmod{p}$. We may then conclude $\gcd(a^p-a, p) = 1$. By Bezout's Lemma, there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $1 = (a^{p-1})x + py$. Re-arranging this expression, we obtain:

$p = \frac{1 - (a^{p-1})x}{y}$

I claim that $y$ divides $1-(a^{p-1})x$. There exists a $j$ such that $yj = 1-(a^{p-1})x$, namely, $p$. We have that $y$ and $1-(a^{p-1})x$ are integers, and $y$ divides $1-(a^{p-1})x$, hence we have that $p$ is not prime.

Comment: You have a wrong step. "Hence, $\gcd(a^p-a, pk)=1$" is not true and should be exchanged with "Hence, $\gcd(a^p-a, p)=1$"

Comment: Since you have got to the solution, it's **recommended** to put  the same solution as an answer and to accept it. This ensures that the question is *answered*. Even if you're not willing, I or @AitorIribarLopez may do it!

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

Suppose that $a$ and $p$ are positive integers, and also that $a^p \not\equiv a\pmod{p}$. We may then conclude that $\gcd(a^p - a, p) = 1$. By *Bezout's Lemma*, there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $1 = (a^{p-1})x + (p)y$. Re-arranging this expression, we obtain...

$$p = \frac{1 - (a^{p-1})x}{y}$$

I claim that $y$ divides $1-(a^{p-1})x$. There exists a $j$ such that $yj = 1-(a^{p-1})x$,  namely, $p$. We have that $y$ and $1-(a^{p-1})x$ are integers, and $y$ divides $1-(a^{p-1})x$, hence we have that $p$ is not prime.